# Is there any major difference between using STM32F103C8T6 + ST LINK V2 and using Tiva c concerning debugging?

Tags: microcontroller, arm, microprocessor, debugging

I have started learning ARM microprocessors and I just wanted some real board to get more comfortable with what i'm learning and I have two options : Getting **tiva c** launch board or using **STM32F103C8T6** basic development board with **ST LINK V2** for programming and "debugging".

I know that these boards use different processors (M3 and M4), but what i'm really worried about is the ability to debug using them. After some googling I knew that "**st link v2**" make the debugging stuff and I have actually found option in **KEIL IDE** that supports debugging using "**st link**" which seems OK but I still need to check if there's any difference or something i'd miss if I choose any of them over the other.

Comment: Both are fully debuggable with the right tools (which can be completely free and opensource - Eclipse+GDB+ OpenOCD).

Comment: The TI Launchpad and STM Discovery boards have the debugger built in so you don't need a separate debugger.  I believe you could use Keil, IAR, or GNU toolchains with both boards and TI adds their own Code Composer toolchain option for the Launchpad.

Comment: The debugger for the Launchpad and Discovery boards use different drivers.  But I don't think you'll notice a difference other than that.  For the Launchpad you'll want to download TI's TivaWare library and examples.  For the Discovery board its STM's STM32Cube library and examples.

Comment: @kkrambo I don't think thatthe specific board that I mentioned has a built in debugger. I know that  STM Discovery boards have the debugger built in but this one is just a very simple board for the processor and a voltage regulator and other simple stuff..

Comment: @EugeneSh. I was looking for other IDEs other than KEIL and IAR so I will check this toolchain and I hope they are suitable for such a beginner :D .